# Is there a way to turn off logging that Hangfire does with serilog?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire, serilog

Is there a way to turn off logging that Hangfire does with serilog? We are using our own abstraction and I don’t want all this extra noise coming from the Hangfire logger while using serilog.

```
// INIT call under web project 
namespace MYApp.Web.App_Start
{
    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            Core.Logging.Serilog.SetConfiguration();
        }
    }
}
```

// project where config method is setup

```
namespace MYApp.Core.Logging
{
 public static class Serilog
    {
      public static void SetConfiguration()
            {

                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    //.WriteTo.File(@"c:\log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute, shared: true)
                    .WriteTo.Email(new EmailConnectionInfo()
                    {
                        FromEmail = "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
                        MailServer = "smtp.gmail.com",
                        ToEmail = "xxxx@xxxx.xx.xx",
                        NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx"),
                        Port = 587,
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        EmailSubject = "YYYYYY: Error Log"
                    }, outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {NewLine} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                    .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire"))
                    .CreateLogger();
            }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define a logger and log provider that does not log anything:

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Logging;

public class NoLoggingProvider : ILogProvider {
    public ILog GetLogger(string name) {
        return new NoLoggingLogger();
    }
}

public class NoLoggingLogger : ILog {
    public bool Log(LogLevel logLevel, Func<string> messageFunc, Exception exception = null) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and configure Hangfire to use it in your `Startup` class:

```
using Hangfire;

public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseLogProvider(new NoLoggingProvider());
        // the rest of your configuration...        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For Dot Net Core,

In appsettings.json, just add "Hangfire" under "MinimumLevel => Override" and value as "**Warning**". This will only log Warning and Error.

If you set as "Override" then it will only log error from hangfire.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could exclude the entire Hangfire namespace (assuming it's all under one namespace -- I've never used it before) using a Filter expression:

`.Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire"))`

Comment: Please add your logging initialization code to your question.

Answer (score 2):

To develop @PatrickSteele's answer, you seemingly need to use the SourceContent of SeriLog. Hangfire has a number of these. This code implements this:

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire.SqlServer.ExpirationManager"))
            .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerObjectsInstaller"))
            .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire.Server.BackgroundServerProcess"))
            .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire.Server.ServerWatchdog"))
            .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire.Server.ServerHeartbeatProcess"))
            .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire.Processing.BackgroundExecution"))
            .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire.SqlServer.CountersAggregator"))
            .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer"))
            .CreateLogger();
```

Of course, this is *my* configuration, which uses SQL Server as a target for logging. It may prove to be useful to collect the various sources from Hangfire in this one place for inclusion in your own code (though this is not necessarily exhaustive).