# How to Disable Hangfire logging in NLog?

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog, hangfire

I am trying to disable Logging with NLog for Hangfire jobs, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Hangfire" : "None"
    }
```

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API Project

NLog version: 4.7.6

NLog.Web.AspNetCore version: 4.10.0

Hangfire version: 1.7.27

Cannot I disable it from appsettings.json?
Instead of using [NLog Logging Rules & Filters](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code), or using some custom NoOpLogger for Hangfire like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52400244/8317898)?

Note: I am using only one rule for my NLog target:

```
var rule= new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, myCustomTarget)
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1809

Comment: Saw that and commented on it already